# Поток QThread в PyQt5 должен дождаться ввода данных

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Условие программы. При нажатие *кнопки 1* запускается поток. Далее срабатывает условие и поток должен дождаться ввода данных в `lineEdit`, а так же нажатие *кнопки 2*, которая отправляет в поток введённую инфу и дальше продолжается работа в этом потоке. Без кнопки всё легко есть `input`, а как с ней не пойму.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 50, 50, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 200, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка 1"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кнопка 2"))


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("Поток запущен")
        x = 2
        if x == 2:  # Условие созданно специально для того что-бы ввести информацию if оставить обязательно

            print("Нажмите на кнопку 2")
            # если делать через консоль то просто пишем self.z = int(input()) дожидаемся ввода и дальше работаем
            # но как сделать если нужно дождаться ввода в окно lineEdit и при нажатие кнопки продолжить выполнение программы
            self.d = self.z + 2  # созданно для примера
            print(self.d)
        else:
            print("")


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.func2)

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.start()

    def func2(self):
        self.z = int(self.lineEdit.text())  # z может быть любым числом


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 30, 350, 70))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 123, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 250, 123, 43))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запустить поток"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выполнит вычисления"))


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

        self.z = 0
        self.flag = False

    def run(self):
        while True: 
#            print("Поток запущен Нажмите на кнопку 2")
            if self.flag:
                self.d = self.z + 2  # созданно для примера
                self.mySignal.emit(self.d, self.z, 2)
                self.flag = False
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)   # < ---


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.func2)
        self.pushButton2.setEnabled(False)

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.mySignal.connect(self.funcSignal)
        self.thread.start()
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton2.setEnabled(True)

    def func2(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text().isdigit():
            self.thread.z = int(self.lineEdit.text())  # z может быть любым числом
            self.thread.flag = True

    def funcSignal(self, rez, a, b):
        self.label.setText("{} = {} + {} \n"
                           "для продолжения введите новое значение \n"
                           "и нажмите кнопку `Выполнит вычисления`".format(rez, a, b))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Лучше ли  использовать объект класса QWaitCondition ? Я утверждать не могу, но пример с его использованием приведу:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 30, 350, 70))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 123, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 250, 123, 43))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запустить поток"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выполнит вычисления"))


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

        self.z = 0
        self._isPause = False
        self.cond     = QtCore.QWaitCondition()
        self.mutex    = QtCore.QMutex()

    def pause(self):
        self._isPause = True

    def resume(self):
        self._isPause = False
        self.cond.wakeAll()

    def run(self):
        while True: 
            self.mutex.lock()
            if self._isPause:
                self.cond.wait(self.mutex)

            self.d = self.z + 2  
            self.mySignal.emit(self.d, self.z, 2)

            self.msleep(100)
            self.mutex.unlock()            

            self.pause()            


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.func2)
        self.pushButton2.setEnabled(False)

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.mySignal.connect(self.funcSignal)
        self.thread.start()
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton2.setEnabled(True)

    def func2(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text().isdigit():
            self.thread.z = int(self.lineEdit.text())   

            self.thread.resume()

    def funcSignal(self, rez, a, b):
        self.label.setText("{} = {} + {} \n"
                           "для продолжения введите новое значение \n"
                           "и нажмите кнопку `Выполнит вычисления`".format(rez, a, b))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Так лучше не делать. Бесконечный цикл порождает большую и ненужную нагрузку на процессор. Лучше использовать объект класса QWaitCondition - вначале ставить его на ожидание, а при получении данных будить и, тем самым, запускать тело потока

Comment: @Alexander Chernin.Не могли бы показать на примере как это сделать?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я убрал нагрузку на процессор. Можете проверить.

Comment: Тоже вариант )  @sens250 я сейчас в отпуске, выйду напишу, но с паузой на 100 мс в вашем случае тоже решение )

Comment: @Alexander Chernin жду ). А пока сам попытаюсь разобраться,интересно как работает.

Comment: @sens250  я добавил пример.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin хорошего вам отдыха.

Comment: @S. Nick.Спасибо )

Comment: @S.Nick поле _isPause не нужно и вызов QThread.msleep тоже

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я не против частных мнений, но правильнее было бы увидеть ваше решение, как вариант.

Comment: Да такое же как у вас только без этого поля и мслипа

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

        self.z = 0
        self.cond     = QtCore.QWaitCondition()
        self.mutex    = QtCore.QMutex()

    def calculate(self, val):
        self.z = val
        self.cond.wakeAll()

    def run(self):
        while True: 
            self.mutex.lock()
            self.cond.wait(self.mutex)

            self.d = self.z + 2  
            self.mySignal.emit(self.d, self.z, 2)
            self.mutex.unlock()
```

И вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
def func2(self):
    if self.lineEdit.text().isdigit():
        self.thread.calculate(int(self.lineEdit.text()))
```